# Railsで任意のルーティングを通したいのですが、ハマっています

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

現在RailsでWebアプリケーションを作っているのですが、ルーティングの部分で解決できない問題があり、わかる方に教えていただければと思います。

**やりたいこと**

記事(articles)のshowアクションが呼び出された時のルーティングが現在は`hoge.com/articles/(記事id)`が表示されてしまいます。それを`/hoge.com/(username)/(記事id)`したいのですが、なかなか出来ません。

routes.rbの中身は以下です。

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
devise_scope :user do
  resources :articles
  get '/:username', controller: 'users', action: 'show'
  get '/users/sign_out', controller: 'devise/sessions', action: 'destroy'
  get 'users/auth/:provider/disconnect', controller: 'omniauth_disconnects', action: 'update'
end
post 'user_invitation_beta_release/new'
get 'static/welcome'
root to: 'root#index'
resources :items
resources :contents
resources :articles do
  resources :contents, only: [:create, :destroy, :change_order] do
    resources :items, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
match "*path" => "application#handle_404", via: :all
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のような表記でよいかと思いますがいかがでしょうか。

```
get '/:username/:id' => 'articles#show'
```